# memcpy: Segfault after second call

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I am writing a wrapper for Karl Malbrain's [AES implementation](http://www.geocities.ws/malbrain/aestable_c.html) to work with input files bigger then 16 bytes.
Therefore, I wrote a functions `aes_encrypt_block` which would split the input buffer (`message`) into blocks of 16 bytes (`chunk` / `chunk_cipher`), calls the encryption/decryption functions and put the encrypted/decrypted 16 bytes back into the result buffer.

This works. However, I need to pad the message before encrypting it. So, the last 16 bytes I encrypt (outside the for-loop) are the padding bytes. When copying these bytes to the output buffer (`cipher`) I get a segfault. I can't really see what is going wrong.

Do you see the mistake?

Regards

```
#include "aes.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG 1

void aes_encrypt_block(uint8_t **message, uint8_t **cipher, uint8_t blocks, uint8_t     pad_bytes);
void aes_decrypt_block(uint8_t **msg_decrypted, uint8_t **cipher, uint8_t blocks,     uint8_t pad_bytes);
unsigned long readFile(char *fileName, uint8_t **buffer);
//unsigned long readFile1(char *fileName, uint8_t *buffer);

uint8_t secret[16] = {0x44, 0x43, 0x45, 0x33, 0x44, 0x03, 0x34, 0x44, 0x43, 0x45, 0x33,     0x44, 0x03, 0x34, 0x03, 0x34};
uint8_t *chunk = NULL;
uint8_t *chunk_cipher = NULL;
uint8_t expanded[176] = {0x00};
uint8_t *buffer = NULL;
uint8_t *cipher = NULL;
uint8_t *msg_decrypted = NULL;
uint8_t mode = -1;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint32_t i = 0;
    uint8_t blocks = -1, pad_bytes = -1;
    unsigned long fileLen;
    char* ch = NULL;

    if(argc<3) {
        printf("Wrong arguments supplied.\n\n%s {0/1} OUT\n\n\t0 - encrypt\n\t1 -     decrypt\n\tOUT - file to read from / to write to.\n\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    } else {
        mode = atoi(argv[1]);
        if(mode<0 || mode>1) {
            printf("Wrong arguments supplied.\n\n%s {0/1} OUT\n\n\t0 -     encrypt\n\t1 - decrypt\n\tOUT - file to read from / to write to.\n\n", argv[0]);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    puts("");

    // Read file
    fileLen = readFile(argv[2], &buffer);
    // Setting up parameters and memory
    if(fileLen%16!=0) {
        printf("- ");
        blocks = fileLen/16+1;
        pad_bytes = (blocks*16)-fileLen;
    } else {
        printf("+ ");
        blocks = fileLen/16+1;
        pad_bytes = 16;
    }
    cipher = malloc((blocks*16)*sizeof(int));
    if(cipher==NULL)    printf("malloc() error!\n");
        aes_expand_key(secret, expanded);
        if(DEBUG)   printf("size: %u, size/16: %d, blocks: %d, padding: %d\n\n", fileLen, fileLen/16, blocks, pad_bytes);

    if(!mode) {     // We will encrypt
        aes_encrypt_block(&buffer, &cipher, blocks, pad_bytes);
        free(buffer);

        FILE *file_enc;
        file_enc = fopen("bla.enc", "wb");
        fileLen = fwrite(&cipher, sizeof(uint8_t), 32, file_enc);
        printf("\nWrote %ld bytes to %s\n", fileLen, argv[2]);
        fclose(file_enc);
    } else {            // We will decrypt
        msg_decrypted = malloc((16*blocks)*sizeof(uint8_t));

        // Decrypting blocks
        aes_decrypt_block(msg_decrypted, cipher, blocks, pad_bytes);

        puts("\nDecrypted message:");
        printf("%s\n", msg_decrypted);
        puts("");
        free(msg_decrypted);
    }

    return 0;
}


unsigned long readFile(char *fileName, uint8_t **buffer) {
    unsigned long fileLen = 0;
    uint8_t i;
    char* ch = NULL;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen (fileName, "rb");  /* open the file for reading */

    if(file==NULL) {
       perror(fileName);
        return 0;
    }
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen=ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    *buffer=malloc(fileLen+1);

    if (!buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }
    fread(*buffer, 1, fileLen, file);
    printf( "Source message in hex(%s, %ld bytes):\n", fileName, fileLen );
    for (ch = *buffer ; ch < *buffer + fileLen; ++ch) {
        printf( "%02X", *ch );
    }
    puts("\nASCII:\n---------");
    for (ch = *buffer ; ch < *buffer + fileLen; ++ch) {
        printf( "%c", *ch );
    }
    puts("");
    fclose(file);

    return fileLen;
}


void aes_encrypt_block(uint8_t **message, uint8_t **cipher, uint8_t blocks, uint8_t pad_bytes) {
    uint8_t i;

    chunk = malloc(16*sizeof(uint8_t));
    if(chunk==NULL) printf("malloc() error!\n");
    chunk_cipher = malloc(16*sizeof(uint8_t));
    if(chunk_cipher == NULL)    printf("malloc() error!\n");

    for(i=0; i<(blocks-1); i++) {
        memcpy(chunk, message[i*16], 16*sizeof(uint8_t));
        aes_encrypt(chunk, expanded, chunk_cipher);
        memcpy(cipher[i*16], chunk_cipher, 16*sizeof(uint8_t));
    }

    // Padding
memcpy(chunk, message[(blocks-1)*16], (16-pad_bytes)*sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint8_t j;
    for(j=0; j<=pad_bytes; j++) {
        chunk[15-j] = pad_bytes;
    }
    aes_encrypt(chunk, expanded, chunk_cipher);
    memcpy(cipher[i*16], chunk, 16*sizeof(uint8_t));
}
```

**EDIT:**

Valgrind output (line 149 in test.c corresponds to: `memcpy(cipher[i*16], chunk, 16*sizeof(uint8_t));`)

```
Valgrind outputs:
InvalidWrite: Invalid write of size 4
Call stack:
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so        0x402E08A: memcpy
/home/dev/aes/test.c|149|0x804A604:        aes_encrypt_block
/home/dev/aes/test.c|59|0x8049AFE:        main
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
Valgrind found 1 errors!
```

Comment: Run it under valgrind.

Comment: Is valgrind available for Windows?

Comment: Does this compile without warnings?

Comment: What is this lne for: `(chunk, message[i*16], 16*sizeof(uint8_t));`?

Comment: @alk: sorry this line got corrupted while formating it for this post. I changed it to the actual line. And yes, it compiles.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Valgrind outputs:

InvalidWrite: Invalid write of size 4

Call stack:
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so  0x402E08A: memcpy|
/home/dev/aes/test.c|149|0x804A604: aes_encrypt_block|
/home/dev/aes/test.c|59|0x8049AFE: main|
||Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd|
||Valgrind found 1 errors!|

Valgrind complains exactly about the same line the segfault appears.

Comment: The question wasn't whether it compiles or not, but if it compiles **without warnings**? If not, fix the code to do so in the first place.

Comment: Which line in the above code corresponds to line 59 in test.c ?

Comment: You might like to add updates to your question into the question itself rather then squezzing it into a comment, which at least is really difficult to read.

Comment: Debugging by blog is like pulling teeth.

Answer (score 2):

If `pad_bytes == 16` then this loop:

```
for(j=0; j<=pad_bytes; j++) {
    chunk[15-j] = pad_bytes;
}
```

will write into an invalid location before the start of `chunk`, possibly corrupting your heap.

It should probably be:

```
for(j=0; j<pad_bytes; j++) {
    chunk[15-j] = pad_bytes;
}
```

Note also that you also appear to have a number of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) where memory allocated via `malloc` is not beeing `free`d, e.g. `chunk` and `chunk_cipher` in `aes_encrypt_block()`.

Comment: Changing the for-loop header does not change the behaviour and still produces the segfault,

Comment: There may well be other bugs to fix too - you should fix the above bug and the various memory leaks and continue to systematically debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this line

```
memcpy(cipher[i*16], chunk_cipher, 16*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

should be

```
memcpy((*cipher) + i*16, chunk_cipher, 16*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

(for the 2nd second call of `memcpy()` apply same to 1st argument)

---

Or even better change the signature of `aes_encrypt_block()` from

```
void aes_encrypt_block(uint8_t **message, uint8_t **cipher, uint8_t blocks, uint8_t pad_bytes)
```

to

```
void aes_encrypt_block(uint8_t **message, uint8_t (*cipher)[16], uint8_t blocks, uint8_t pad_bytes)
```

and do

```
memcpy(cipher + i, chunk_cipher, sizeof(*cipher));
```

(for the 2nd second call of `memcpy()` apply same to 1st argument)